# How to express residue

Tags: complex-analysis

I have struggled a lot to solve that exercise: How to express the following 
$\operatorname{Res}(\sin(e^z/z), 0))$ as a series. I tried to expand in Taylor Series, but I came across a multinomial series that is hard to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach:
$$
 \sin\bigl(\frac{e^z}{z} \bigr) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \bigl(\frac{e^z}{z} \bigr)^{2k+1}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \frac{e^{(2k+1)z}}{z^{2k+1}} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \frac{1}{z^{2k+1}}
\sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{((2k+1)z)^l}{l!}
$$
The residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the 
Laurent series, and entries in the double sum contribute to that
coefficient exactly if $l = 2k$. The residue at $z=0$ therefore is
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)^{2k}}{(2k+1)!(2k)!}
$$
I don't know if that can be simplified further.